# SELECT statement executing fine in SQL Management Studio but not VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I run the following statement in SQL management studio and it retrieves all the correct rows and columns.

When I run in VB.net it gives an error "Invalid column name 'category_id'".

The column definitely exists, and as I said it works fine in SQL management studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        Dim sqlDocuments As String = "SELECT 
                                    d.*, 
                                    cat.name AS 'Category', 
                                    rd.name AS 'Rev Description', 
                                    co.name AS 'Source', 
                                    ds.smiley AS 'Smiley', 
                                    CONCAT(cr.first_name, ' ', cr.last_name) AS 'Created By', 
                                    CONCAT(m.first_name, ' ', m.last_name) AS 'Modified By', 
                                    CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS 'Checked By', 
                                    CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) AS 'Approved By', 
                                    CONCAT(tc.first_name, ' ', tc.last_name) AS 'To Check', 
                                    CONCAT(ta.first_name, ' ', ta.last_name) AS 'To Approve', 
                                    CONCAT(o.first_name, ' ', o.last_name) AS 'Owner', 
                                    CONCAT(cv.name, '\', cvp.path) AS 'Custom View', 
                                        (SELECT TOP 1 Attachment.id 
                                        FROM [Attachment] 
                                        WHERE d.id = document_id) AS 'Attachment', 
                                        (SELECT CONCAT(cat.name, '\', disc.code, ' - ', disc.name, '\', dt1.code, ' - ', dt1.name, '\', dt2.code, ' - ', dt2.name) 
                                        FROM [MyApp].[dbo].[Classification] cl 
                                        JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Category] cat 
                                        ON cl.category_id = cat.id 
                                        JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Discipline] AS disc 
                                        ON cl.discipline_id = disc.id 
                                        JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Document_Type] AS dt1 
                                        ON cl.document_type_id = dt1.id 
                                        JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Document_Type_2] AS dt2 
                                        ON cl.document_type_2_id = dt2.id 
                                        WHERE d.classification_id = cl.id) AS 'Classification', 
                                        CONCAT(co2.name, '\', po.number) AS 'Vendor PO' 
                                    FROM [Project].[dbo].[Document] d 
                                    JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Classification] cl 
                                    ON d.classification_id = cl.id 
                                    JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Category] cat 
                                    ON cl.category_id = cat.id 
                                    INNER JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Revision_Description] rd 
                                    ON d.revision_description_id = rd.id 
                                    INNER JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Company] co 
                                    ON d.source_id = co.id 
                                    INNER JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Document_Status] ds 
                                    ON d.status_id = ds.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS cr 
                                    ON d.created_by_id = cr.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS m 
                                    ON d.modified_by_id = m.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS c 
                                    ON d.checker_id = c.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS a 
                                    ON d.approver_id = a.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS tc 
                                    ON d.to_check_id = tc.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS ta 
                                    ON d.to_approve_id = ta.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] AS o 
                                    ON d.owner_id = o.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [Custom_View_Document] cvd 
                                    ON cvd.document_id = d.id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [Custom_View_Path] cvp 
                                    ON cvp.id = cvd.path_id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [Custom_View] cv 
                                    ON cv.id = cvp.view_id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Purchase_Order] po 
                                    ON po.id = d.po_id 
                                    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Company] co2 
                                    ON co2.id = po.vendor_id 
                                    JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Project] p 
                                    ON d.project_id = p.id 
                                    WHERE d.hidden = 0 
                                    AND p.number = '00000001';"
```

Comment: Check the connection string to make sure you are executing the query against the same server and database that you ran the query against successfully in SSMS.

Comment: Considering that you are using 3 part naming, I strongly suspect you're not connecting to the correct instance; as connecting to the wrong database won't cause an issue if as you've provided the database name as part of the object's name.

Comment: On a totally different note, consider making use of whitespace when writing SQL.  Everything being aligned to the same left margin doesn't make for easy reading.

Comment: Both, thank you for your responses. I only have 1 instance and as Larnu said I can only specify 1 database in my connection string but I have to provide the database names anyway to allow a cross database JOIN. This statement has been working, the only thing I changed was originally 'category_id' was also in the [Document] table, but as I have 'category_id' in the [Classification] table there was no need to have it on both. The [Document] table has a 'classification_id' which I can use to JOIN and retrieve the 'category' that way. But again regardless the query works fine in SQL. Very annoying

Comment: A query won't work in one application and not in enough if nothing is different. The fact that you are saying that the query is working in SSMS very strongly points to the fact that you aren't connected to the same instance. Otherwise, it might be that the definition of the table has been changed since you tried the query in SSMS; meaning that again something is different. The only place I can see you reference `category_id` is with the alias `cl`; which is the object `Classification`. I would suggest checking that table.

Comment: Also, I advise against reuse of aliases in the same query. You use the same alias for your objects both in your `FROM` and your subqueries. Although an alias *should* always to refer to any objects within the same subquery first, it does make the alias ambiguous. I'd suggest using a different alias for the object. For example, you could suffix the alias with `sq`,so you know that the alias is in the context of the subquery, rather than the `FROM`.

Comment: Larnu, thanks again for responding. I don't know what more to say, I have 1 instance this is correct and hasn't changed, it works for all my other SQL queries within VB. 'category_id' with the 'cl' alias does exist in 'Classification'. For proof my connection string is correct I have added the 'category_id' column back into the [Document] table and changed the SQL query back to as it was. They are the only changes, please see code as additional post. And it works fine... I don't understand, that's why I have come to stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly if I run my new code now that I have added 'category_id' column back into the [Document] table I don't receive an error. Why is it still looking in the [Document] table when I've clearly got it written with alias cl both times it is used? Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty confident this is telling you the problem. You don't have a column `category_id` in your table `Classification`. Impossible to tell without DDL though, but the error basically tells us this is true.

Comment: I mean I'm in the Management Studio now looking at the table design and I can see the column. Also the query works in management studio. It works when I add the column to the [Document] table. It's like VB is looking a different table to SQL MS. It's just boggling me completely. I guess I'll start the query fresh with no sub queries etc. and just keep introducing each part back and see how I get on. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Notice that you are using at least **3 different databases** in your query - MyCompany, MyApp,and Project. Some references are relative to the current database of the connection - so that could imply a 4th database. You need to think very carefully about this approach as it is easy to get confused about what is where. Based on what you posted, you are only creating future problems for yourself. Moving everything into a single database is the safest and sanest thing you can do.